# UmbracoIdentity SSO with existing ASP.Net MVC5

Tags: asp.net-identity, umbraco7

Hello I am new to Singal Sign On and I have a task on hand to make my existing MVC application share the credentials with Umbraco and once login from my application, it should not need to login again when user click a link on my application and then redirect to Umbraco.

The structure I have in my mind should contains three parts: an identity provider, my application and Umbraco. Is it correct?

I would like to use UmbracoIdentity and ASP.Net Identity, is it possible? I did googled a few days but I can't find a detailed tutorial/guide for this, may someone give me some advice/link?

Thanks.